# Sending http request from android to app engine

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, http

I am trying to find out how to send an http request from android app to google app engine datastore but I coundn't find the API and example codes.

can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

[Load request](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/adminconsole/instances#Loading_Requests)

And the other option is change your API for other Google API:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/channel/

You can read more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18318424/send-data-quickly-to-google-app-engine-from-android)

Comment: I need this requests in order to insert/update/remove items from the datastore. I am not sure that's what I need from the overview.  Is it what I'm looking for?